# Pandas Shift Column & Remove Row

Tags: pandas, indexing, multiple-columns, shift

I have a dataframe 'df1' that has 2 columns and i need to shift the 2nd column down a row and then remove the entire top row of the df1.

My data looks like this:

```
   year   ER12
0  2017  -2.05
1  2018   1.05
2  2019  -0.04
3  2020  -0.60
4  2021 -99.99
```

And, I need it to look like this:

```
   year   ER12
0  2018  -2.05
1  2019   1.05
2  2020  -0.04
3  2021  -0.60
```

Comment: So basically you want to remove the top row and start indexing from `0`?

Comment: @user2100039 did any of the proposed answer work for you? Don't forget to give feedback and vote/select on the working answers

Answer (score 1):

We can try this:

```
df = df.assign(ER12=df.ER12.shift()).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
   year  ER12
0  2018 -2.05
1  2019  1.05
2  2020 -0.04
3  2021 -0.60
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on your example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2017,2018,2019,2020,2021], 'ER12':[-2.05,1.05,-0.04,-0.6,-99.99]})
df['year'] = df['year'].shift(-1)
df = df.dropna()
```